# Payflow zero amount authorization(Account verification) not working for me

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, payflowpro

Currently I am using Payflow gateway in one of my integrations. However, the Account verification which is also known as zero amount authorization which they have mentioned on their website(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/) does not work for me. Following is the example that they have provided on their  website:

TRXTYPE=A&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&USER=SuperUser&PWD=SuperUserPassword&AMT=0.00&ACCT=378282246310005
&EXPDATE=1215&INVNUM=PONUM1&VERBOSITY=HIGH&BILLTOZIP=95031

I tried it with this example and also edited a few other things such as I added vendor and CVV in the example but none of them seem to work. The error code that I get is 12 and the response message is declined. I know they have mentioned to contact issuing bank but I don't think the problem is related to bank because when I enter 0.01 amount the authorization passes without any error.

It will be really helpful if someone can provide a working example of account verification or zero amount authorization.

Kind Regards
Het Parikh.

Answer (score 0):

The card that you have used in this example is AMEX: 378282246310005. There was a similar issue that I had which PayPal fixed. Probably you can try again and see if it works.

Comment: Is that a real credit card number? If it is, please replace *at least some* of the numbers with x!! Same goes for your other answer.